# Convert expensive call to async while keeping event system intact

Tags: c#, async-await

I am facing some issues trying to optimize some older code. The overall picture is this: There is an 'export engine' that spins up some 'writer' object depending on the desired output. The write spins up a `DataReader` object and subscribes to its events so it can process the data being read. It then starts a long-running 'GetData' method in the reader. This retrieves data from a legacy database which takes a long(!) time. The datareader processes the returned values and fires several events that allow the writer to handle the data.

A very much simplified pseudo-code example of the DataReader is included below.

```
class DataReader
{
    // delegates
    internal delegate void DataRowReadHandler(object sender, DataRowReadArgs e);
    internal delegate void DataProgressChangedHandler(object sender, DataProgressChangedArgs e);
    internal delegate void DataReadCompleteHandler(object sender, DataReadCompleteArgs e);
    // events
    internal event DataProgressChangedHandler DataProgressChanged;
    internal event DataReadCompleteHandler DataReadCompleted;
    internal event DataRowReadHandler DataRowRead;

    // this methods chomps on and on and raises an event when the database read returns something
    internal void GetData()
    {
        for (int totalrows = 0; totalrows < _cursor.RowCount; totalrows += _maxrows)
        {
            // I want to keep GetRawData running while the data it fetched is being processed
            string[][] rawdata = _cursor.GetRawData(_maxrows);

            // -- a ton of post-processing I want to do while database is being read--

            // and then report progress
            foreach (row in rawdata)
            {
                DataRowReadArgs args = new DataRowReadArgs(row.Index)
                OnDataRowRead(args); // raise event after each row
            }
            DataProgressChangedArgs args = new DataProgressChangedArgs(batch, counter);
            OnDataProgressChanged(args); // raise event after each batch of rows
        }
        // report we're done
        DataReadCompleteArgs e = new DataReadCompleteArgs(counter);
        OnDataReadCompleted(e); // done with reading data
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataProgressChanged(DataProgressChangedArgs e)
    {
        DataProgressChangedHandler handler = DataProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataReadCompleted(DataReadCompleteArgs e)
    {
        DataReadCompleteHandler handler = DataReadCompleted;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataRowRead(DataRowReadArgs e)
    {
        DataRowReadHandler handler = DataRowReadRead;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

What I want: to keep the database-reading (which will be by far the slowest) running, and process the returned data whenever a query result becomes available. That is: post-process the data in the reader, have it fire events, and have the handlers in the writers deal with them *while the database reading continues*. Ideally, I also want some cancelation token to stop the reading when something goes wrong, but first things first. I do NOT want to touch the event-based system that a lot of classes rely on, I only want the database read to run in parallel and have the rest of the code respond whenever there is a result.

I have dabbled with await/async and TaskCompletionSource and whatnot for almost a week now but still don't seem to be able to wrap my brain around this. I've gotten close, I actually managed to compile a list of tasks, feed that to an intermediate method that would process each task as it finishes, and await that.

```
internal async Task GetDataAsync()
{
    IList<Task<string[][]>> tasks = CreateCursorReadTasks();
    var processingTasks = tasks.Select(AwaitAndProcessAsync).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
    // this isn't 'awaited' in the sense I expected
    // also, what order are they performed in? The database is single-threaded, no queues, nothing
    // I need to fire my 'done' event only after all tasks have finished
}

private IList<Task<string[][]>> CreateCursorReadTasks()
{
    IList<Task<string[][]>> retval = new List<Task<string[][]>>();
    for (int totalrows = 0; totalrows < this._cursor.RowCount; totalrows += _maxrows)
    {
        retval.Add(Task.Run(() => _cursor.GetRawData(_maxrows)));
    }
    return retval;
}

internal async Task AwaitAndProcessAsync(Task<string[][]> task)
{
    string[][] rawdata = await task;
    // Do all the post-processing and fire the events like in the GetData method of DataReader
}
```

Apart from this all seeming overly complex, I run into two problems: a) my event handlers all seem to be null even though I subscribed to them and b) I do not where/how to raise the completed event.

My question is: when you look at my `GetData` method in the `DataReader` class, how would you suggest I go about making the very expensive database calls run async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use modern opportunities: producer/consumer pattern via [pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff963548(v=pandp.10)) with [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Inside your `GetData` method start two Tasks: one for getting data, second for processing data.

You can still use your event system. Just at the same time add data to the collection, which won't take long.

In the second task, the data is extracted from the collection and processed. Waiting on the `GetConsumingEnumerable` method is done very efficiently.

```
class DataReader
{
    public CancellationTokenSource CTS { get; } = new CancellationTokenSource();

    internal void GetData()
    {
        // Use the desired data type instead of string
        var values = new BlockingCollection<string>();

        var readTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                // here your code
                for (...)
                {
                    if (CTS.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;

                    foreach (var row in rawdata)
                    {
                        DataRowReadArgs args = new DataRowReadArgs(row.Index);
                        //...
                        values.Add(args); // put value to blocking collection
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) { /* process possible exception */}
            finally { values.CompleteAdding(); }

        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        var processTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var value in values.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                if (CTS.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;

                // process value
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        Task.WaitAll(readTask, processTask);            
    }
}
```

You can cancel tasks at any time:

```
var dataReader = new DataReader();
dataReader.GetData();
dataReader.CTS.Cancel();
```

Instead of `Task.WaitAll` you can use `await Task.WhenAll(readTask, processTask);`
In this case, the method signature should be as follows: `async Task GetDataAsync()`

Comment: Thank you Marius and Alexander for your helpful input. Will try your suggestions shortly.

Comment: I finally got your code running. Interestingly enough it runs slightly slower than my synchronous implementation. Probably due to overhead created behind the scenes. But I had a very interesting experience trying.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo code seems ok, I tried to verify it with a program where I simulated the calls to the database with `Task.Delay(5000)` and only allow access for one task at any moment (to account for the fact that the database is single threaded).

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataReader = new DataReader();
        dataReader.DataProgressChanged += (s, e) => Log.D($"*** Event - Processed {e.TaskId}");
        dataReader.DataReadCompleted += (s, e) => Log.D("*** Event - Data read complete");

        await dataReader.GetDataAsync();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class DataReader
{
    internal delegate void DataProgressChangedHandler(object sender, DataProgressChangedArgs e);
    internal delegate void DataReadCompleteHandler(object sender, DataReadCompleteArgs e);

    internal event DataProgressChangedHandler DataProgressChanged;
    internal event DataReadCompleteHandler DataReadCompleted;

    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    internal async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        Log.D("Start");
        var tasks = CreateCursorReadTasks();
        var processingTasks = tasks.Select(AwaitAndProcessAsync).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
        OnDataReadCompleted(new DataReadCompleteArgs());
    }

    private IList<ReadTaskWrapper> CreateCursorReadTasks()
    {
        var retval = new List<ReadTaskWrapper>();
        for (int totalrows = 0; totalrows < 4; totalrows++)
        {
            int taskId = totalrows;
            retval.Add(new ReadTaskWrapper
            {
                Task = Task.Run(async () => { return await SimulateDbReadAsync(taskId); }),
                Id = taskId
            });
        }
        return retval;
    }

    private async Task<string[][]> SimulateDbReadAsync(int taskId)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        Log.D($"Starting data read task {taskId}");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Log.D($"Finished data read task {taskId}");
        semaphore.Release();
        return new string[1][];
    }

    internal async Task AwaitAndProcessAsync(ReadTaskWrapper task)
    {
        string[][] rawdata = await task.Task;
        Log.D($"Start postprocessing of task {task.Id}");
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        Log.D($"Finished prostprocessing of task {task.Id}");

        OnDataProgressChanged(new DataProgressChangedArgs { TaskId = task.Id });
    }

    internal void OnDataProgressChanged(DataProgressChangedArgs args)
    {
        DataProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    internal void OnDataReadCompleted(DataReadCompleteArgs args)
    {
        DataReadCompleted?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    internal class DataProgressChangedArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
    }

    internal class DataReadCompleteArgs : EventArgs
    {
    }
}

public class ReadTaskWrapper
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Task<string[][]> Task { get; set; }
}

public static class Log
{
    public static void D(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}: {msg}");
    }
}
```

The output suggests that it runs correctly. In the example 4 tasks are started and the database access takes 5 seconds each time while post processing takes 3 seconds (to make it obvious). Total running time is about 23 seconds (4 * 5 + 3), that means that the post processing is executed in parallel to the database reads. The events fire also as expected. The order in which the tasks are executed is different each time the program is run. See the following program output:

```
15:54:20: Start
15:54:20: Starting data read task 2
15:54:25: Finished data read task 2
15:54:25: Starting data read task 0
15:54:25: Start postprocessing of task 2
15:54:28: Finished prostprocessing of task 2
15:54:28: *** Event - Processed 2
15:54:30: Finished data read task 0
15:54:30: Starting data read task 3
15:54:30: Start postprocessing of task 0
15:54:33: Finished prostprocessing of task 0
15:54:33: *** Event - Processed 0
15:54:35: Finished data read task 3
15:54:35: Start postprocessing of task 3
15:54:35: Starting data read task 1
15:54:38: Finished prostprocessing of task 3
15:54:38: *** Event - Processed 3
15:54:40: Finished data read task 1
15:54:40: Start postprocessing of task 1
15:54:43: Finished prostprocessing of task 1
15:54:43: *** Event - Processed 1
15:54:43: *** Event - Data read complete
```

In order to investigate further: where do you instantiate the `DataReader` class in your program and how do you subscribe to the events? Can you describe in more detail what you mean by the comment "this isn't 'awaited' in the sense I expected"?

Comment: This is a little complex to describe. In essence, a consumer creates an ExportEngine object (can be via COM). The consumer supplies a Settings object to it. Based on the Settings object, a Writer object is created. There are several Writer objects (one for Text, one for XML, etc.) that derive from an abstract base. The base class has a ReadData method that is called from all derived Writer. It creates a DataReader object, subscribes to its events and then calls a ReadData (there are several) method in the reader. The derived Writers then process the read data via event handlers.

Comment: As for subscribing, the `ReadData` method in the base `Writer` class subscribes to the events in the `DataReader` class it just created via the usual way, e.g. `dr.DataRowRead += HandleDataRowRead;`

Comment: In the different Writers, these handlers are overridden so as to do whatever they should do.

Comment: As for the `await WhenAll()` not doing what I expected, I expected that it would wait for all reading tasks to be completed, and then fire the 'I'm done' event (not shown in example, but right after the await WhenAll()). In reality it is fired almost immediately. This is bad because writers rely on it for closing file streams etc..